# Notepad++ CSS Files

Tags: notepad++

When I open a CSS file which has each property on a new line it inserts an extra new line in between so they have a whole line separation in between them. I would love for this to not happen however I have not found any way to stop this from happening. Anyone got ideas?

Notepad++ v5.7

TextFX v0.26

Plugins:

Compare, MIME Tools, NppExport, NppFTP, Select 'N Launch

Comment: what version and plugins have you got running? I'm not getting this behaviour.

Comment: Added version information to original post

Comment: Are you opening this file in other editors?  What format is your end of line (EOL) character in?  What type of server are you using the CSS file from?

Comment: Not opening in any others besides older versions of NPP, EOL is unix like, the file is on my local machine

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your NP++ config is somehow corrupt.
You might try a fresh install of the latest version which is 5.9.2 as of now.

Uninstall NP++, clear the %APPDATA%/Notepad++ directory if in use,
and reinstall the new version, fire up the plugin manager to get your plugins of choice.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen before. However, I realized that it was not caused in Notepad++ but rather in another part of my workflow. I believe the place it happens to me is during FTP file transfer. I use Filezilla.

It could be an encoding issue via `UTF-8`/`ANSI` or other compatibility issue when transferring over FTP. I notice this happens a lot with wordpress files including `php` files.

However, again, the issue is most likely not notepad++ but another part of the workflow. Notepad++ just opens the file as it is.

If you are certain notepad++ caused it, try opening in a generaic notepad window or viewing the file over in your web file browser. Chances are you will see that is just how the file looks, and notepad++ did not cause the issue.

When it occurs with me by the way I fix by doing a find/replace with `\n\n` > `\n`. This just takes every 2x `new line` and makes it just one `new line`. (`\n` stands for `new line`). Make sure `Extended` is checked. Isn't always a perfect solution but usually does the trick.

It doesn't solve your original issue since your original issue is not caused by notepad++, but it is a quicker way to remove extra lines.

[image]

Hope this helps.